# React - Array if-else filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a products list, that is divided in categories and subcategories.

I populate them by creating a group from props, checking if the group has any subGroups in it and adding it below, and finally populate groups with products according to what group they are in.

```
  const SideBarMenu = props => {
  const groups = props.groups;
  const products = props.products;
  const handleClick = props.handleClick;

  const AddGroup = group => {

    return (
      <SubMenu
        key={"group-id-" + group.id}
        title={
          <span>
            <Icon type="appstore" />
            <span>{group.name}</span>
          </span>
        }
      >
        {group.subGroups.length
          ? group.subGroups.map(subGroup => AddGroup(subGroup))
          : null}
        {products
          ? products
              .filter(product => product.groupID === Number(group.id))
              .map(product => AddMenuItem(product))
          : null}
      </SubMenu>
    );
  };

  // TODO: Add "empty item warning" in empty groups?
  const AddEmptyMenuItem = () => {
    return <Menu.ItemGroup title="There appears to be nothing here"></Menu.ItemGroup>
  }

  const AddMenuItem = product => {
    return <Menu.Item key={product.productID}>{product.name}</Menu.Item>;
  };

  return (
    <Menu triggerSubMenuAction="click" id="sidebar-menu" onClick={handleClick} mode="inline" selectable>
      {groups ? groups.map(group => AddGroup(group)) : null}
    </Menu>
  );
};
```

Now what I want to do is, to render a AddEmptyMenuItem element that would go to any group where there are no products, just to add to user experience.

My problem is that no matter how hard I try working around `filter` method, it just doesn't work for me

How would I check whether the filter returns any results, if it does, call `AddMenuItem(product)`, and if, in the end, it found no results for the said condition, call `AddEmptyMenuItem`?

Comment: I don't see any attempted use of `AddEmptyMenuItem` in your code, where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to return the array that you need instead of handling intensive calculations in jsx.

```
{calibrateProductStatus(products)}

calibrateProductStatus = (products) => { 
    if(products.length){
        let filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.groupID === Number(group.id));
        return filteredProducts.length? filteredProducts.map(product => AddMenuItem(product)) : AddEmptyMenuItem()
    } else return null;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar thing going, but for some odd reason, at the very last group that I have, under every category I get the the empty menu item while it is still populated.
https://imgur.com/a/ISTxxlV